# Delay in assigning reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Is this normal?

I normally see this once the 200 reputation cap is reached, not before.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's normal. Weird, but normal. The reason is because of the un-upvote you received (the -10). This day still counts towards the badges that say that you have to earn a total of 200 reputation, because you still *earned* as much when you count together the green numbers. That total of 190 can be ignored.

You can see similar things for example when placing a bounty. A bounty of 50 means you are "capped" at +150 - but the day still counts towards the badges for 200.